# can the master unregister a node instead of killing it when another node with the same name is started?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and had the below question
For my application ,i want the master to unregister a node instead of killing it ,when a new node with the same name is started . Is this possible in ROS ?

Please suggest possible solution , thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303526/can-the-master-unregister-a-node-instead-of-killing-it-when-another-node-with-the-same-name-is-started-?/) by [jithinreju@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/37550/jithinreju@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, that is not supported at this time.

New nodes with a name that is already used will cause the "old node" to be killed, as all names must be unique.

Can you clarify why you'd want to have two nodes running with the same name?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jithinreju@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/37550/jithinreju@gmail.com/) on 2018-09-17**:
I was working on a cloud application and here the latency is an issue.Since the old node is killed, to restart the node again on the machine takes some time and this was not okay for my application and hence I was looking for a solution to deregister it and then later register during connection loss

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-17**:
In case of ROS1 and cloud, perhaps a [multimaster setup](http://wiki.ros.org/multimaster_fkie) would be more appropriate?

> to deregister it and then later register during connection loss

"and later REregister" you mean?

**Comment by [jithinreju@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/37550/jithinreju@gmail.com/) on 2018-09-17**:
off course I could use anonymous name, but this complicates the application because of other dependencies and I wanted to explore this option of unregistering and registering ,which seemed like a quick solution .But this is possible only if I could prevent it from killing it when cloud node active

**Comment by [jithinreju@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/37550/jithinreju@gmail.com/) on 2018-09-17**:
yes I mean later reregister

**Comment by [jithinreju@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/37550/jithinreju@gmail.com/) on 2018-09-17**:
just to be more specific ,my application is more like an edge computing architecture, where the server keeps changing and hence I though it was better to have a single master and everytime I have a new edge server I deploy the computing ros node to it and then change to another edge server with time